# Is there an easy way to implement a proxys HTTP requests and translates them to SSL?

Tags: java, python, ssl, proxy

I am looking for a Proxy that is basically going to execute all SSL traffic for me, but me (the client) requests only HTTP.

I tried implementing my own but it has been a really tough job. I am looking for an easy/smooth API to build this kind of proxy upon.

Any tips?

Comment: hmm.. why do you need that? You can take a look at my [http lib](http://bayou.io/release/0.9/docs/http/Http_Intermediary.html). Basically, the proxy accepts an `HttpRequest`, transform it to one with [`isHttps`](http://bayou.io/release/0.9/javadoc/bayou/http/HttpRequest.html#isHttps--)`= true`, and send it to downstream.

Comment: I think it's probably because of "HTTP Public Key Pinning". The browser has a list of known hosts, including facebook; the browser will not send HTTP or go through proxy for these hosts; no man-in-the-middle of any kind. Not sure how to configure that in Firefox. Try IE which probably has not yet supported the feature.

Comment: Please do not deface your questions. As a new member of Stack Overflow, you may want to read the introductory [tour] some time.

Comment: @bayou.io Ok, thanks. I tried IE but it's still refusing the connection. Maybe it's because it's redirecting me to HTTPS? If so, is it possible to get the response header - and replace the https location redirect to an http, so that the request can go through the proxy as http and converted  by me?

Comment: @bayou.io Since the http request is redirecting me to https, the proxy is refusing the connection since it's setting is an HTTP proxy. Is there a way to set the HTTPS redirect to only HTTP using your lib? Thank you for the answer!

Comment: see my answer --- I haven't tested though :) good luck.

Comment: It's also possible that a javascript sees that the current page is "http", and tries to redirect to "https". In theory we could also examine server HTML/JS response contents, and modify anything. But that's getting harder I guess.

Comment: @bayou.io Ok, thank you. I will try to examine the response content and try to change it. Another question (last one, I promise :)). I got an handshake expection when trying to hit certan URL:s. To solve this, I used SslConf and called trustAll(), but it didn't work and I am still getting SSL exceptions. Is it possible to just ignore everything and trustAll (which I thought the method would do)?

Comment: What's the exception message?

Comment: transformed: https://sr.symcd.com/MFYwVKADAgEAME0wSzBJMAkGBSsOAwIaBQAEFHQkFGcGn%2FXgmD9ePhproGUqVBV1BBQBWavn3ToLWaZkY9bPIAdX1ZHnagIQH0YdvitjjBnKyyuOvQv3dg%3D%3D

2016-02-01 19:12:32.294 [bayou selector thread #0 #fiber# http connection #6 [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] GET /MFYwVKADAgEAME0wSzBJMAkGBSsOAwIaBQAE...] ERROR bayou.http.HttpServer - [error id: C10490A6#0] javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem

Comment: General SSLEngine problem .... :) Any more specific cause/reason you can find in the stack trace?

Comment: Sorry, here's the whole stack trace. :) 
http://justpaste.it/r2es

Comment: try config `downstream` to `trustAll`, if you haven't already done so. See my answer.

Comment: @bayou.io Thank you. Do you have a support channel or email list for bayou? In case I stumble upon any other issues?

Comment: actually, it's probably the "host name verification"; i.e. the cert is valid, but its host does not match the request host. (someone reuse a valid cert for another host, which is a no-no, because they want you to pay for each host :) See my edit again.

Comment: You are welcome to raise questions to the mailing list. See http://bayou.io/info.html.

Answer (score 0):

If this is incoming traffic, you could look for solution like this : http://www.apsis.ch/pound/

If this is for outgoing request, you can use requests : http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example proxy I wrote using [`bayou.io`](http://bayou.io/release/0.9/docs/http/Http_Intermediary.html); it will transform any `http://stackoverflow.com` requests to `https://`

```
    HttpClient downstream = new HttpClient();
    HttpHandler handler = request->
    {
        ...

        if( !request.isHttps() && request.host().equals("stackoverflow.com"))
        {
            request = new HttpRequestImpl(request).isHttps(true);
            System.err.println("transformed: "+request.absoluteUri());
        }

        return downstream.send0(request, null);
    };

    HttpServer proxy = new HttpServer(handler);
```

See full code at https://gist.github.com/zhong-j-yu/0ca082a264082e267cd4

You can examine and transform server responses as well. For example, if the server wants to redirect to `https://xxx`, we want to fix it to `http://xxx`

```
    HttpHandler handler = request->
    {
        ...

        return downstream
            .send0(request, null)
            .map( response->fixRedirect(response) );

    }




static HttpResponse fixRedirect(HttpResponse serverResponse)
{
    if(serverResponse.statusCode()!=303)
        return serverResponse;

    String location = serverResponse.header(Headers.Location);
    if(location==null || !location.startsWith("https"))
        return serverResponse;

    // server tries to redirect to an https://xxx url. change it to http://xxx
    location = "http" + location.substring(5);

    return new HttpResponseImpl(serverResponse)
        .header(Headers.Location, location);
}
```

To trust any server SSL certificate, we need to configure `downstream`

```
    // trust all certs
    SslConf sslConf = new SslConf()
        .trustAll();

    // disable host name verification
    ConsumerX<SSLEngine> sslEngineConf = engine->
    {
        SSLParameters sslParameters = engine.getSSLParameters();
        sslParameters.setEndpointIdentificationAlgorithm(null);
        engine.setSSLParameters(sslParameters);
    };

    HttpClientConf clientConf = new HttpClientConf()
        .sslEngineConf(sslEngineConf)
        .sslContext(sslConf.createContext());

    HttpClient downstream = new HttpClient(clientConf);
```

Comment: WOW, exactly what I was looking for! Is there any way to make it generic so it translates everything that is http to https on that port?

And, does it support post data and such without me adding 80 lines of code? 

Thanks

Comment: But not every website supports HTTPS... Many small websites don't. It won't work to send an HTTPS request to an HTTP-only server.

Comment: yes, POST and all common features are supported.